# Python Error: ValueError: Non-integer arg 1 for randrange()

Tags: python, random

I'm getting the above error in my code. It's just a simple text-based game.

Here's the code:

```
import os
import sys
import random

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = 100
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.attack = 10
        self.gold = 0
        self.potions = 0

class Goblin:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = 50
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.attack = 5
        self.goldgain = 10

GoblinIG = Goblin("Goblin")

class Zombie:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = 70
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.attack = 7
        self.goldgain = 15

ZombieIG = Zombie("Zombie")

def main():
    #os.system("cls")
    print("Welcome to my game!")
    print("1) Start")
    print("2) Load")
    print("3) Exit")
    option = input("-> ")
    if option == "1":
        start()
    elif option == "2":
        pass
    elif option == "3":
        pass
    else:
        main()

def start():
    #os.system("cls")
    print("Hello, what is your name?")
    option = input("-> ")
    global PlayerIG
    PlayerIG = Player(option)
    start1()

def start1():
    #os.system("cls")
    print("Name: %s" % PlayerIG.name)
    print("Attack: %s" % PlayerIG.attack)
    print("Gold: %i" % PlayerIG.gold)
    print("Potions: %i" % PlayerIG.potions)
    print("Health: %i/%i" % (PlayerIG.health, PlayerIG.maxhealth))
    print("1) Fight")
    print("2) Store")
    print("3) Save")
    print("4) Exit")
    option = input("-> ")
    if option == "1":
        prefight()
    elif option == "2":
        store()
    elif option == "3":
        pass
    elif option == "4":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        start1()

def prefight():
    global enemy
    enemynum = random.randint(1,2)
    if enemynum == 1:
        enemy = GoblinIG
    else:
        enemy = ZombieIG
    fight()

def fight():
    print("%s       vs      %s" % (PlayerIG.name, enemy.name))
    print("%s's Health: %s/%s       %s Health: %i/%i" % (PlayerIG.name, PlayerIG.health, PlayerIG.maxhealth, enemy.name, enemy.health, enemy.maxhealth))
    print("Potions Left: %s\n" % PlayerIG.potions)
    print("1) Attack")
    #Implement defend system
    print("2) Drink Potion")
    print("3) Run")
    option = input()
    if option == "1":
        attack()
    elif option == "2":
        drinkPotion()
    elif option == "3":
        run()
    else:
        fight()

def attack():
    global PlayerAttack
    global EnemyAttack
    PlayerAttack = random.randint(PlayerIG.attack / 2, PlayerIG.attack)
    EnemyAttack = random.randint(enemy.attack / 2, enemy.attack)
    if PlayerAttack == PlayerIG.attack / 2:
        print("You missed!")
    else:
        enemy.health -= PlayerAttack
        print("You dealt %i damage!" % PlayerAttack)
    option = input(" ")
    if enemy.health <= 0:
        win()
    if EnemyAttack == enemy.attack/2:
        print("The enemy missed!")
    else:
        PlayerIG.health -= EnemyAttack
        print("The enemy dealt %i damage!" % EnemyAttack)
    option = input("")
    if PlayerIG.health <= 0:
        dead()
    else:
        fight()

def drinkPotion():
    if PlayerIG.potions == 0:
        print("You don't have any potions!")
    else:
        PlayerIG.health += 50
        if PlayerIG.health >= PlayerIG.maxhealth:
            PlayerIG.health = PlayerIG.maxhealth
        print("You drank a potion!")
    option = input(" ")
    fight()

def run():
    runnum = random.randint(1,3)
    if runnum == 3:
        print("You have ran away!")
        option = input(" ")
        start1()
    else:
        print("You've failed to run away!")
        option = input(" ")
        EnemyAttack = random.randint(enemy.attack / 2, enemy.attack)
        if EnemyAttack == enemy.attack/2:
            print("The enemy missed!")
        else:
            PlayerIG.health -= EnemyAttack
            print("The enemy dealt %i damage!" % EnemyAttack)
        option = input(" ")
        if PlayerIG.health <=0:
            dead()
        else:
            fight()

def win():
    enemy.health = enemy.maxhealth
    PlayerIG.gold -= enemy.goldgain
    print("You have defeated the %s!" % enemy.name)
    print("You found %i gold!" % enemy.goldgain)
    option = input(" ")
    start1()

def dead():
    print("You have died!")
    option = input(" ")

def store():
    pass

main()
```

I get the error in def run(), in the else: statement. The line that goes like: EnemyAttack = random.randint(enemy.attack / 2, enemy.attack)

Any ideas? Should I elaborate more on my issue? Thanks :)

Comment: show the complete traceback

Answer (score 0):

Use `EnemyAttack = random.randint(math.floor(enemy.attack / 2), enemy.attack)`, or use `math.ceil()` to round the result of `enemy.attack / 2`.

`randrange()` expects whole integers. The error is occurring because the result of `enemy.attack / 2` isn't a whole number; it has decimal places whenever `enemy.attack` is odd. One option is to scale `randrange()` *after* it is calculated if you need decimal results.

For example: `0.5*randrange(2*(enemy.attack/2), 2*enemy.attack)`, which can be simplified into `0.5*randrange(enemy.attack, 2*enemy.attack)`

Comment: why not just enemy.attack // 2?  That's always an integer if enemy.attack is an integer.

Comment: In this case, it seems python has a rather simple solution and by all means, I recommend its use. Many other languages do not, so I think pointing out language-agnostic approaches has merits as well.

Comment: @Aaron3468 , your answer gave me the idea to just simply give the enemy attack strengths even numbers that are evenly divisible by two.

Thanks :)

Comment: @Aaron.  Your statement that many programming languages lack a simple integer division operator is very strange.  I've been writing programs since 1978, in many languages, and I've never seen one.  BTW your solution is not only needlessly complicated, it also produces a float, not an int, since the multiplication by 0.5 converts the value returned by randrange into a float.

Comment: @gurgy11 Making all the integers even works fine until, in the next version, you decide to change the divisor from 2 to 3.  Perhaps it's better to just use the // operator.

Comment: @PaulCornelius do note that scaling it afterwards is not my recommended solution but another option should the application require a range of floats.

Comment: @PaulCornelius, ya, I had thought of that, I'll probably just implement your solution now, and sort of make it a "habit" to use this. It's a rather simple solution. :)